# Update Labels/Button Texts dynamically

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I created this .ui file using PyQt designer, and I call this via the 2nd script(which has some data processing as well) How do I make the QPushButton i.e Confirmed, Active, Recovered, and Deaths(The numbers next to it are just a placeholder, I want to update them to the data processed from the main script) Tried converting it .py couldn't figure out.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>COVID19_Updater</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="COVID19_Updater">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>917</width>
    <height>615</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <property name="styleSheet">
   <string notr="true">background-color: rgb(5, 25, 55);</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout">
    <item row="0" column="0">
     <widget class="QFrame" name="frame">
      <property name="maximumSize">
       <size>
        <width>16777215</width>
        <height>16777215</height>
       </size>
      </property>
      <property name="styleSheet">
       <string notr="true">QFrame{
    
    
    background-color: rgb(5, 25, 55);

    border-radius: 10px
}</string>
      </property>
      <property name="frameShape">
       <enum>QFrame::StyledPanel</enum>
      </property>
      <property name="frameShadow">
       <enum>QFrame::Raised</enum>
      </property>
      <widget class="QLabel" name="Title">
       <property name="geometry">
        <rect>
         <x>-10</x>
         <y>20</y>
         <width>921</width>
         <height>61</height>
        </rect>
       </property>
       <property name="font">
        <font>
         <family>Segoe UI</family>
         <pointsize>25</pointsize>
        </font>
       </property>
       <property name="styleSheet">
        <string notr="true">color: rgb(3, 122, 245);
lable.adjustSize();</string>
       </property>
       <property name="text">
        <string>&lt;strong&gt;COVID-19&lt;/strong&gt; &lt;i&gt;LIVE&lt;/i&gt;</string>
       </property>
       <property name="alignment">
        <set>Qt::AlignCenter</set>
       </property>
      </widget>
      <widget class="QLabel" name="Description">
       <property name="geometry">
        <rect>
         <x>-10</x>
         <y>70</y>
         <width>921</width>
         <height>61</height>
        </rect>
       </property>
       <property name="font">
        <font>
         <family>Segoe UI</family>
         <pointsize>10</pointsize>
        </font>
       </property>
       <property name="styleSheet">
        <string notr="true">color: rgb(190, 191, 196);</string>
       </property>
       <property name="text">
        <string>&lt;html&gt;&lt;head/&gt;&lt;body&gt;&lt;p&gt;Realtime COVID-19 status of all Countries including &lt;span style=&quot; font-weight:600;&quot;&gt;Indian&lt;/span&gt; States and Districts&lt;/p&gt;&lt;/body&gt;&lt;/html&gt;</string>
       </property>
       <property name="textFormat">
        <enum>Qt::MarkdownText</enum>
       </property>
       <property name="alignment">
        <set>Qt::AlignCenter</set>
       </property>
       <property name="wordWrap">
        <bool>true</bool>
       </property>
      </widget>
      <widget class="QPushButton" name="CheckData">
       <property name="geometry">
        <rect>
         <x>300</x>
         <y>190</y>
         <width>281</width>
         <height>61</height>
        </rect>
       </property>
       <property name="font">
        <font>
         <family>Segoe UI Emoji</family>
         <pointsize>15</pointsize>
         <weight>50</weight>
         <bold>false</bold>
        </font>
       </property>
       <property name="focusPolicy">
        <enum>Qt::StrongFocus</enum>
       </property>
       <property name="layoutDirection">
        <enum>Qt::LeftToRight</enum>
       </property>
       <property name="styleSheet">
        <string notr="true">background-color: rgba(0, 122, 255,50);

color: rgb(3, 122, 245);
border-radius: 30px;

</string>
       </property>
       <property name="text">
        <string>Check Live Data</string>
       </property>
       <property name="checkable">
        <bool>false</bool>
       </property>
      </widget>
      <widget class="QLabel" name="AuthorName">
       <property name="geometry">
        <rect>
         <x>730</x>
         <y>570</y>
         <width>161</width>
         <height>21</height>
        </rect>
       </property>
       <property name="font">
        <font>
         <family>Segoe UI</family>
         <pointsize>8</pointsize>
        </font>
       </property>
       <property name="cursor">
        <cursorShape>IBeamCursor</cursorShape>
       </property>
       <property name="styleSheet">
        <string notr="true">color: rgba(190, 191, 196,95);</string>
       </property>
       <property name="text">
        <string>&lt;html&gt;&lt;head/&gt;&lt;body&gt;&lt;p&gt;Created by: &lt;span style=&quot; font-style:italic;&quot;&gt;Sumukh Jadhav&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;/body&gt;&lt;/html&gt;</string>
       </property>
       <property name="textFormat">
        <enum>Qt::MarkdownText</enum>
       </property>
       <property name="alignment">
        <set>Qt::AlignBottom|Qt::AlignRight|Qt::AlignTrailing</set>
       </property>
       <property name="wordWrap">
        <bool>true</bool>
       </property>
       <property name="textInteractionFlags">
        <set>Qt::LinksAccessibleByMouse|Qt::TextSelectableByMouse</set>
       </property>
      </widget>
      <widget class="QPushButton" name="UpdataData">
       <property name="geometry">
        <rect>
         <x>300</x>
         <y>290</y>
         <width>281</width>
         <height>61</height>
        </rect>
       </property>
       <property name="font">
        <font>
         <family>Segoe UI Emoji</family>
         <pointsize>15</pointsize>
         <weight>50</weight>
         <italic>false</italic>
         <bold>false</bold>
         <underline>false</underline>
         <strikeout>false</strikeout>
        </font>
       </property>
       <property name="focusPolicy">
        <enum>Qt::StrongFocus</enum>
       </property>
       <property name="layoutDirection">
        <enum>Qt::LeftToRight</enum>
       </property>
       <property name="styleSheet">
        <string notr="true">background-color: rgba(0, 122, 255,50);

color: rgb(3, 122, 245);
border-radius: 30px;

</string>
       </property>
       <property name="text">
        <string>Update Status</string>
       </property>
       <property name="checkable">
        <bool>false</bool>
       </property>
      </widget>
      <widget class="QPushButton" name="Confirmed">
       <property name="geometry">
        <rect>
         <x>20</x>
         <y>460</y>
         <width>201</width>
         <height>81</height>
        </rect>
       </property>
       <property name="font">
        <font>
         <family>Helvetica LT Std</family>
         <pointsize>15</pointsize>
         <weight>75</weight>
         <italic>false</italic>
         <bold>true</bold>
         <underline>false</underline>
         <strikeout>false</strikeout>
         <kerning>true</kerning>
        </font>
       </property>
       <property name="focusPolicy">
        <enum>Qt::StrongFocus</enum>
       </property>
       <property name="layoutDirection">
        <enum>Qt::LeftToRight</enum>
       </property>
       <property name="styleSheet">
        <string notr="true">
background-color: rgba(112,108,195,50);

color: rgb(112,108,195);


</string>
       </property>
       <property name="text">
        <string>Confirmed
 2,94,59,649</string>
       </property>
       <property name="checkable">
        <bool>false</bool>
       </property>
      </widget>
      <widget class="QPushButton" name="Active">
       <property name="geometry">
        <rect>
         <x>240</x>
         <y>460</y>
         <width>201</width>
         <height>81</height>
        </rect>
       </property>
       <property name="font">
        <font>
         <family>Helvetica LT Std</family>
         <pointsize>15</pointsize>
         <weight>75</weight>
         <italic>false</italic>
         <bold>true</bold>
         <underline>false</underline>
         <strikeout>false</strikeout>
        </font>
       </property>
       <property name="focusPolicy">
        <enum>Qt::StrongFocus</enum>
       </property>
       <property name="layoutDirection">
        <enum>Qt::LeftToRight</enum>
       </property>
       <property name="styleSheet">
        <string notr="true">
background-color: rgba(238, 14, 63,50);

color: rgb(238, 14, 63);


</string>
       </property>
       <property name="text">
        <string>Active
 72,41,136</string>
       </property>
       <property name="checkable">
        <bool>false</bool>
       </property>
      </widget>
      <widget class="QPushButton" name="Recovered">
       <property name="geometry">
        <rect>
         <x>460</x>
         <y>460</y>
         <width>201</width>
         <height>81</height>
        </rect>
       </property>
       <property name="font">
        <font>
         <family>Helvetica LT Std</family>
         <pointsize>15</pointsize>
         <weight>75</weight>
         <italic>false</italic>
         <bold>true</bold>
         <underline>false</underline>
         <strikeout>false</strikeout>
        </font>
       </property>
       <property name="focusPolicy">
        <enum>Qt::StrongFocus</enum>
       </property>
       <property name="layoutDirection">
        <enum>Qt::LeftToRight</enum>
       </property>
       <property name="styleSheet">
        <string notr="true">background-color: rgba(46, 155, 80,50);
color: rgb(42, 160, 79);


</string>
       </property>
       <property name="text">
        <string>Recovered
 2,12,92,324</string>
       </property>
       <property name="checkable">
        <bool>false</bool>
       </property>
      </widget>
      <widget class="QPushButton" name="Deaths">
       <property name="geometry">
        <rect>
         <x>680</x>
         <y>460</y>
         <width>201</width>
         <height>81</height>
        </rect>
       </property>
       <property name="font">
        <font>
         <family>Helvetica LT Std</family>
         <pointsize>15</pointsize>
         <weight>75</weight>
         <italic>false</italic>
         <bold>true</bold>
         <underline>false</underline>
         <strikeout>false</strikeout>
        </font>
       </property>
       <property name="focusPolicy">
        <enum>Qt::StrongFocus</enum>
       </property>
       <property name="layoutDirection">
        <enum>Qt::LeftToRight</enum>
       </property>
       <property name="styleSheet">
        <string notr="true">background-color: rgba(110, 116, 128,50);
color: rgb(110, 114, 126);

</string>
       </property>
       <property name="text">
        <string>Deaths
 9,33,150</string>
       </property>
       <property name="checkable">
        <bool>false</bool>
       </property>
      </widget>
      <widget class="QPushButton" name="UpdataData_2">
       <property name="geometry">
        <rect>
         <x>300</x>
         <y>420</y>
         <width>281</width>
         <height>31</height>
        </rect>
       </property>
       <property name="font">
        <font>
         <family>Gravity</family>
         <pointsize>13</pointsize>
         <weight>75</weight>
         <italic>true</italic>
         <bold>true</bold>
         <underline>false</underline>
         <strikeout>false</strikeout>
        </font>
       </property>
       <property name="focusPolicy">
        <enum>Qt::StrongFocus</enum>
       </property>
       <property name="layoutDirection">
        <enum>Qt::LeftToRight</enum>
       </property>
       <property name="styleSheet">
        <string notr="true">

color: rgb(169, 206, 244);
border-radius: 30px;

</string>
       </property>
       <property name="text">
        <string>Current World Data</string>
       </property>
       <property name="checkable">
        <bool>false</bool>
       </property>
      </widget>
     </widget>
    </item>
   </layout>
  </widget>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

Main script

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, uic
import sys
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import re

url = 'https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/'
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

class Ui(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Ui, self).__init__()
        uic.loadUi('AutoSize.ui', self)
        self.show()


app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
window = Ui()
app.exec_()

data = []

for x in range(0, 3):
    x = soup.find_all(class_ = 'maincounter-number')[x].find('span').text
    data.append(x)

Active = int((re.sub("[],]","", data[0]))) - (int((re.sub("[],]","", data[1]))) + int((re.sub("[],]","", data[2]))))

res = "{:,}".format(Active)


con = data[0]
det = data[1]
rec = data[2]
act = str(res)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The task of obtaining the information is very time consuming so it should not be executed in the main thread but in a secondary thread, and send the information through signals. The OP does not clearly describe what event it should be updated before so in my example I will use a QTimer to update every T seconds:

```
import sys
import threading

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, uic

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests


class Scrapper(QtCore.QObject):
    dataChanged = QtCore.pyqtSignal(tuple)

    def start(self):
        threading.Thread(target=self._execute, daemon=True).start()

    def _execute(self):
        url = "https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/"
        page = requests.get(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")

        data = []

        for e in soup.find_all(class_="maincounter-number"):
            value = int(e.find("span").text.strip().replace(",", ""))
            data.append(value)

        total, deaths, recovered = data
        active = total - deaths - recovered

        self.dataChanged.emit((total, deaths, recovered, active))


class Ui(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Ui, self).__init__()
        uic.loadUi("AutoSize.ui", self)

        self.s = Scrapper()
        self.s.dataChanged.connect(self.update_data)
        self.s.start()

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(tuple)
    def update_data(self, data):
        total, deaths, recovered, active = data

        self.Confirmed.setText("Confirmed\n{:,}".format(total))
        self.Active.setText("Active\n{:,}".format(active))
        self.Recovered.setText("Recovered\n{:,}".format(recovered))
        self.Deaths.setText("Deaths\n{:,}".format(deaths))

        QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(2 * 1000, self.s.start)


def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    window = Ui()
    window.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: This code says ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '29,675,950'
I want to get the total, deaths, active and recovered into the UI

Comment: Yes, just copy-pasted the whole thing again, same error :( Seems to be a problem while declaring data = []

Comment: If you don't mind, can you explain to me what's happening here? This is my first time using UI

Comment: @SumukhJadhav My answer clearly explains what I implement, I think you do not understand precisely because it is *This is my first time using UI*, and unfortunately neither SO nor I are tutors, I recommend you review tutorials, bye.